# Recover Raid 5 array

Tags: raid

I have just broke my software RAID 5 Array (build using mdadm) set up by changing one of the HDD partition.

The exact command I used is:

```
sudo parted -s /dev/sdb mklabel msdos
```

on one of 4 HDDs in my array.

Is there a way how to fix this HDD and add it back to array without loosing any data?

I'm very new to linux, so now sure how to show you more info about my set up.

Mike

Comment: Are you using hardware or software Raid?

Comment: I'm using software raid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to add the 4th disk back to the raid?** "From Mike's Question in previous comment"

Edit this for your needs:

```
mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/sdf1
mdadm --grow /dev/md1 --raid-devices=4
```

This then took several hours to reshape the array.

The filesystem the needs to be expanded to fill up the new space.

```
fsck.ext3 /dev/md1
resize2fs /dev/md1
```

Comment: Thanx Subv3rsion that will do it :)

Comment: That is how to add a new disk to an array, and expand it to use the additional space, not how to fix @Mike's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool named **raidextract**.

Example usage:

```
./raidextract --window 1024 --stripe 16 --rotate 6 \
    --start $((0x41C6E79A00)) --length $((4096*1024*64000)) \
    --failed 5 /dev/sd[a-g] | ssh othermachine dd of=RecoveredFilesystem
```

If you use raidextract to read a filesystem image, you can write the output to a file and run all the standard filesystem tools (tune2fs, e2fsck) on the file. Once you've finished, you can the mount the filesystem with mount -o loop.

For more information, you can read this: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~peterb/linux/raidextract/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers Subv3rsion, unfortunately I dont have other HDD where can I output 3TB of data to :( I thought that by having Raid-5 one of the HDD is redundant and all data could be easily recovered if one hdd dies.

Comment: Well, note that RAID isn't a backup system.

Comment: One more thing, can you try do a XFS repair? then try to mount it again.

Comment: ok, I managed to start the raid in degraded state and mount it. Good news is I can access all the data. How to add the 4th disk back to the raid?

Answer (score 0):

If the only thing you did was blow away the partition table with `parted`, then all you have to do to fix it is to recreate the partition table exactly as it was before.  Put `parted` into sector mode with the `unit s` command, and you can probably look at the other disks in the array to guess how this one was partitioned.